# Where's the error in 她的表演感染了观众，她的声音也像她的穿戴一样，银铃般美丽?

Tags: grammar

From the HSK6 Standard Course workbook (chapter 6, page 45; [photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vltyT.jpg); OCR from Yandex), we have the following "faulty sentence" question:

> 19. A 我的生活中有很多令我满意的事情，我现在很满足。
>     B 这是我第一次面对这么多人演讲，坦率地说，非常紧张。
>     C **她的表演感染了观众，她的声音也像她的穿戴一样，银铃般美丽**。
>     D 成功人士都会告诉你，什么时候都不能没有梦想，没有梦想就不会成功。

The given answer is C; no explanation is provided.  This faulty sentence was asked about [on HiNative](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/23970890), but unfortunately it was inputted incorrectly as:

> 她的表演感染了观众，她的声音也像她的穿戴一样，银铃般**美的**。

Another user corrected this to 美的 -〉的美.  They don't explain what the problem actually is, which is really the point of doing such exercises, so you can apply the newly learned skill the next time you encounter it.

It seems the adjective 美丽 can describe 声音 (there's [many examples online](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E7%BE%8E%E4%B8%BD%E7%9A%84%E5%A3%B0%E9%9F%B3%22)).  The HiNative answer look like they don't like 美丽 because it's an adjective, and they're trying to change it to a noun.

**Question**: Where's the error in 她的表演感染了观众，她的声音也像她的穿戴一样，银铃般美丽?

Comment: Quote:- "It seems the adjective 美丽 can describe 声音 (there's many examples online)" Yes, but notice that they all say 美丽的声音 and not 声音的美丽? That's because 美丽的声音 means "Beautiful sounds", such as the beautiful sound of tinkling  bells; but 声音的美丽 means "the beauty of sounds" in general.

Answer (score 2):

> "她的**声音**也像她的**穿戴**一样，银铃般美丽"

"声音像穿戴"是一個不恰當的比擬. 声音可分為(似物般的)清脆和(如人般的)甜美/柔美. The sentence can be acceptable if it says: "她的声音银铃般的清脆, 也像她人一样的甜美/柔美.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence,

> 她的表演感染了观众, 她的声音也像她的穿戴一样, 银铃般美丽.

can be reorganizes as,

> 她的表演感染了观众, 她的声音像银铃般清脆, 穿戴也非常美丽.

When using **analogy word 像**, you describe the audial effect with an object that makes a sound and the visual effect with an object that looks attractive. You can not analogize **声音** with **穿戴**.

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong adjective and object match**

声音(voice) should be 银铃般悅耳 (pleasant to the ear like a silver bell), not 銀鈴般美丽 (beautiful like a silver bell)

> [銀鈴般](https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=156634&la=0&powerMode=0)

> 形容聲音清脆悅耳。如：「教室裡充滿了銀鈴般的笑聲和歌聲。」(Describes the sound as crisp and sweet. For example: "The classroom was filled with laughter and singing like silver bells.")

More obvious examples:

"I am tough as a flower"

"She is beautiful like a brick"

Note:

银铃 might also be beautiful, but 銀鈴般 (like a silver bell) already has the default usage of "pleasant to the ear",  using this adjective to describe something beautiful is not natural at all. The preferable adjective for something beautiful is "花朵般"  (like a flower)

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, 美丽 is not suitable.

A beautiful sound
动听的声音

Take

她的表演感染了观众，她的声音也像她的穿戴一样，银铃般美丽。

and change to

她的表演感染了观众，
Her performance infected the audience,
她的声音也像她的穿戴一样，
and her voice, as beautiful as her attire,
银铃般动听。
was like a silver bell.